# Re-Enable Landing page in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke and Mistakenly have disabled the landing page of the my site built in DotNetNuke and now i am neither allowed to access my site nor am i able to login to my site.

How can i re-enable the disabled landing page.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://www.yoursite.com?ctl=login

This will allow you to login aa then you can update the settings.

Comment: It doesn't work as it still tries to redirect to the landing page

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to get into the database and edit the PortalSettings table's content.

What setting did you actually change on your website? One of the "pages" drop downs from the Admin/Site Settings?

Look in the portalsettings table and find the columns for Login Home Splash page, etc, and set those to Null.

Though if you didn't change that, perhaps you mean you changed the "default" page in IIS? IF that is the case try going to www.yourwebsite.com/default.aspx?ctl=login to login